# Paython script not finding files

Tags: python

I have following script which is supposed to list all picture etc from my disk drives, but it failes to find any file. Any Idea what I may be doing wrong. I am doing in PyCharm environment:

```
    files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith((".jpg", ".jpeg", ".mp3", ".mp4")):
                files.append(os.path.join(root, file))

    # Sort the files by their current folder name
    files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.dirname(x))

    # Display a list of the files
    for file in files:
        print(file)
```

Comment: What kind of error does it give you?

Comment: Looks like problem will be with using variable files twice. Once to append with results, but also for os.walk.

Comment: PyCharm loves to do everything in venvs. That could be a source of your trouble. To help debug you could put `print(os.getcwd())` to print the current working directory of your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for-loop will never end as you add the found file name into `files` which you are looping through. Use another variable to store the list.

This works fine:

```
import os

results = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    print(f"Got: {len(results)} files, current dir: {root}")
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith((".jpg", ".jpeg", ".mp3", ".mp4")):
            results.append(os.path.join(root, file))
            
# Sort the files by their current folder name
results.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.dirname(x))

# Display a list of the files
for file in results:
    print(file)
```

Comment: I am not getting error, this just end without displaying any file.

Comment: the code works fine when `files` variable is replaced be a new variable; What do you mean by "end without displaying any file" , like the script ends and does not print anything?